# Powershell Start-Process to run another Powershell script with more history

Tags: powershell, start-process

Using `Start-Process` I can call another powershell script within my powershell script.

e.g. `Start-Process powershell -argument '.\Another.ps1`

The issue is the new Window only has a limited amount of history (i.e. scroll back up to see what was printed out)

Is there any way to increase the history size from `Start-Process`?

If not, how do you call another powershell script that can have more history size?

Comment: `$Size = $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize; $Size.Height += 100; $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize = $Size`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks. How does this relate to the new powershell process?

Comment: It does not. It is the command, which expand buffer size for current PowerShell process. You need to put it in script for new PowerShell process.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you. Yeah your code works but I need something to call another script with the expended windows history to start with, can't edit the other script.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the **MaximumHistoryCount** in this case for that particular session.

> Get-Variable MaximumHistoryCount | Select-Object -ExpandProperty
>   attributes

You can set the maximum value then.

```
Set-Variable -Name MaximumHistoryCount -Value 32767
## Check it again using the range also 
Get-Variable -Name MaximumHistoryCount | Select-Object -ExpandProperty attributes | Format-List -Property *Range
```

**Note:** You cannot give value for than *32767*. That is the upper limit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide the full code as to how this changes the new powershell process?

Comment: Sure. I have modified the answer. Please check it. Accept if it helps you.

Comment: No it doesn't work. I think you misunderstood my question. I was talking about the windows history (amount of lines you can scroll up to read), not the command history.